# Celery - How to update the state of a task after the worker's being shutdown?

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery, python-2.x, celery-task

### Setup

Celery 3.0

broker=RabbitMQ

### Scenario

Tasks have already been acknowledged and started processing, and have `state=STARTED`. Then I want to restart my worker (to update the worker to a newer version). After restart worker (using `supervisorctl restart`), those long running tasks are all been terminated. But their states remain in `state=STARTED`. How can I update their state to `FAILURE` or whatever other values? (And, I don't want these tasks being executed again after the worker restarts.)

### Methods tried (but not working)

- use `track_started=True` --- If with this option, the tasks stay at `state=STARTED` after the worker restarts. If without this option, the tasks stay at `state=PENDING` after the worker restarts.
- use `CELERY_ACKS_LATE=True` --- The tasks stay at `state=STARTED` after the worker restarts. And tasks are executed again, not a desired behavior.
- use `signal(SIGTERM, handler)` and a handler function to catch the signal. The handler can successfully be entered. However, no matter what thing I put inside the handler, it can't change the task's state. The states just stay as the same and won't change to `FAILURE`. Inside the handler I've tried

  - `raise Exception`
  - `exit(0)`
  - `exit(1)`

Is there any settings of Celery that could enable it to track the state of task being shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

You need to revoke the tasks on worker shutdown. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3076) issue for the actual code.

Comment: (1) To `revoke` needs a task to be in `reserved` state. For my case, all the tasks have already been executed, they can't be revoked.
(2) The resource code in your link does 2 things, `revokes reserved tasks` and `aborts active tasks`. Neither of these 2 things make the states of tasks change from `STARTED` to `FAILURE`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the better way would be adjust `stopwaitsecs` ([see](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html)) in your supervisor config to be more than your time limit per task. Supervisor would wait for your tasks to finish without killing them. So your tasks always finished normally and no states to fix in the first place.

Also this depends on how long your tasks are. And if they too long running to wait for them, may be it's better to split them to shorter ones.

Comment: Every task runs for about 1 hour, so I would prefer just killing it. And to split the tasks into sub tasks would need a lot extra result & error handling, therefore we currently are not considering this solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I find the last method (`signal(SIGTERM, handler)`) you tried working. Since the code successfully enter the TERM signal handling branch, the crux becomes how to update the state of task. Simply use `self.update_state(state=states.FAILURE)` inside the task body.

Here's an example:

```
import time    
import signal
from celery import Celery, states

app = Celery("celery")

@app.task(bind=True)
def demo(self):
    
    def mark_as_fail(*args):
        self.update_state(state=states.FAILURE)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, mark_as_fail)

    for i in range(30):
        print(f"I am demo task {i}")
        time.sleep(1)
```